# Unable to install libopencv-dev via apt-get

Tags: apt, dpkg, opencv

I am attempting to install `libopencv-dev` via `apt-get install`. So I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

and it seems to install the package. However, when I inspect the directory where the lib files should be, I do not see them.

According to dpkg, this directory is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. But the lib files are neither here nor are they anywhere else on my computer.

How do I troubleshoot this? I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling libopencv-dev to no avail.

Compiling an opencv c++ program results in the following errors:

```
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so: No such file or directory
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so: No such file or directory
```

I use `pkg-config --cflags --libs` to link the c++ program to the opencv libs. The output of running  `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` is:

```
-I/usr/include/opencv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so -lopencv_calib3d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so -lopencv_contrib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -lopencv_core /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so -lopencv_features2d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so -lopencv_flann /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so -lopencv_gpu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so -lopencv_highgui /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so -lopencv_imgproc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so -lopencv_legacy /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so -lopencv_ml /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so -lopencv_objdetect /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so -lopencv_ocl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so -lopencv_photo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so -lopencv_stitching /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so -lopencv_superres /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so -lopencv_ts /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so -lopencv_video /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so -lopencv_videostab
```

Comment: AFAIK `libopencv-dev` itself doesn't provide any libraries (although its dependencies do). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 16.04. I am trying to compile a c++ program that requires opencv, but it fails to compile because none of the opencv libraries are found. When I run dpkg -l, it indicates that all the opencv packages are installed, but I don't see the libraries anywhere.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the compiler command that is failing, along with the error message. Also the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

Comment: Well although it seems like [pkg-config is broken in OpenCV-2.4.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4359) and later (it should be using `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` rather than prepending the individual library paths) that doesn't seem to stop it working. All I can suggest is that you `autoremove` the dependent packages and try again i.e. `sudo apt autoremove libopencv-dev` followed by `sudo apt install libopencv-dev`

Answer (score 1):

When you remove `libopencv-dev` some opencv lib are not removed, running:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep opencv
```

You can check if some lib is still there and remove it. Then you can try to reinstall libopencv. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484540/no-rule-to-make-target-libopencv-calib3d-so-3-2-0-but-opencv-3-4-1-installed-wh/61565434#61565434) could help.